# DevExpress XtraGrid update on lost focus

Tags: c#, devexpress, auto-update, xtragrid, lost-focus

I want to disable the update event of the grid when the focus of the row is lost. So, after i added/edited a record and click on a previous record the grid should NOT update. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need the grid to not update? what happens that you dont need/like

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you want to make (all) grid rows unfocused and focus once the user clicks the grid. If yes, please refer:

[Is it possible to set up the grid to have no focused row?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A902)

Comment: In this article it states that "The XtraGrid always has a focused row...". So maybe I am asking the wrong question. What event fires that causes the update? for example, when you click on another record or if I click anywhere outside the grid.